# Locked out of admin panel after installing HC Custom WP-Admin URL

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, wp-admin

I installed "HC Custom WP-Admin URL" plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/hc-custom-wp-admin-url/) on my WordPress installation, and then changed the admin slug value to a cryptic url (http://example.com/some-cryptic-string) so that the default (http://example.com/wp-admin) is not visible. Unfortunately now, for some reason, I am unable to unable to see either of the URLs. Effectively, I am now locked out of the CP.

I have full access to the database via the hosting provider's cpanel and phpmyadmin.

Any way that I can come out of this situation?

Comment: Rename your plugin folder. This should deactivate all your plugins.

Comment: ...unless this plugin wrote something into the htaccess file which it apparently does.

Comment: have u tried to go to login page directly by /wp-login.php ? it should show you the form to login and after login redirect to dashboard

Comment: @PieterGoosen, the answer below solves the problem, so I don't think I need to go that way. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @kraftner, no, I don't think it writes into the htaccess file.

Comment: @Najeeb When looking at http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/hc-custom-wp-admin-url/trunk/hc-custom-wp-admin-url.php it appears at least it should. Just skimmed the code though...

Comment: (y) though it hadn't written in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you sad u have access to phpmyadmin.

Go to it, find `wp_options` table

Look for `custom_wpadmin_slug` in option_name and in `option_value` column will be your's custom defined `wp-admin` slug

If you'll still wount be able to access then remove next lines in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^{your_wp_admin_slug}/?$ {your_site.com/}wp-login.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that `{your_wp_admin_slug}` is equal to one in `wp_options` table

Comment: Hey thanks @Maikal, it worked. I deleted the option_value field in the row (did NOT delete the row, though), and /wp-admin/ started working just fine.